# Find the Minimum amount needed for a man

Tags: c, debugging

A person has to cross a road and with each step he either gains some energy or loses some (this info is provided as an array) . Find out the min amount of energy he should start with so that at any level his energy is not less than 1.

But the below program always prints "Error" not the number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
int main(){
    int a[]={10,20,20};
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

    int ans = calldistance(a,n);
    if(ans==-1)
        printf("error");
    else 
        printf("%d",ans);
    return 0;
}

int calldistance(int a[],int n){
    int i,min=INT_MAX;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){ 
        min+=a[i];
        if(min<1) return -1; 
        else continue;
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: This has the feel of a classical backtracking problem. And your program is invalid, and should produce an error. Is it your actual code? Or did you slap something together hoping we'd solve it for you?

Comment: @StoryTeller no recursion necessary. Just 1 pass through the array. (I might be wrong...)

Comment: Did anybody _stared_ at the title or is it only me? :D

Comment: @bolov - It's not quite clear to me what a "step" is. But if each step is going to the next array cell, then yes. A single pass will do.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - What *is* the measure of a man? :P

Comment: @StoryTeller Amount on "uni"s in his possession, I'd say. :)

Comment: Hint: Adding something to INT_MAX will cause ???

Comment: "the Minimum amount needed for a man" is 42. It's just by coincidence that 42 is also the answer to life the universe and everything

Comment: @Ankur - undefined behavior

Comment: @Senbagaraman  It is women who define the minimum amount needed for a man.:)

Comment: Why does it have to be a man?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Jokes Apart :).I found this problem but cant able to solve.The array stated above can also have negative values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always return `-1` because you call it quits if the array is one where the value isn't trivial.

You need to keep track of partial sums of the array. In particular you need to know when the partial sum is at its lowest negative value (or zero). The absolute value of this + 1 is your answer.

If the sum is never bellow 1, then your answer is just 1.

```
int calldistance(const int a[], const int n) {
    int min_partial_sum = 0;
    int partial_sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { 
        partial_sum += a[i];
        if(min_partial_sum > partial_sum)
           min_partial_sum = partial_sum;
    }

    if(min_partial_sum < 0)
      return -min_partial_sum + 1;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: is this the correct solution?(sorry if it is offence in asking-a novice programmer  here)

Comment: @Senbagaraman - You mean have I written tests for it to see if it covers as many possible input variations as possible? No. this is your task. I only wrote what I understood from your problem statement. Take it or leave it.

Comment: Will try ,no issues in that .Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int calldistance(int a[],int n){
    int i,min=INT_MAX;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){ 
        min+=a[i];
        if(min<1) return -1; 
        else continue;
    }
    return min;
}
```

In the above function you are initializing `min=INT_MAX` and if you add even 1, it will return a negative number. That's the why you are always getting `error` as answer.

Comment: min=INT_MIN also returns -1 :(

Comment: why add min=INT_MIN, just put min=0

Comment: signed integer overflow is Undefined Behavior

Comment: anything greater than 2^31 in signed integer will result in negative number as the sign bit is turned high.